# How to get vanity_url resolved in ActiveAdmin belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin, belongs-to

I'm adding ActiveAdmin to a mature application and having difficulty getting the route generation to work for a belongs_to relationship.  Here is the class relationship:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
     vanity_url.blank? ? id.to_s : vanity_url
  end
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

This is important because we use routes such as `domain/projects/awesome_project` instead of `domain/projects/215`.  All pretty standard stuff.

In ActiveRecord, I've gotten the relation correctly defined with:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
end

ActiveAdmin.register Job do
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I believe this is correct because the route generated include:

```
admin_project_jobs     GET      /admin/projects/:project_id/jobs(.:format)                                      admin/jobs#index
                       POST     /admin/projects/:project_id/jobs(.:format)                                      admin/jobs#create
new_admin_project_job  GET      /admin/projects/:project_id/jobs/new(.:format)                                  admin/jobs#new
edit_admin_project_job GET      /admin/projects/:project_id/jobs/:id/edit(.:format)                             admin/jobs#edit
admin_project_job      GET      /admin/projects/:project_id/jobs/:id(.:format)                                  admin/jobs#show
... etc
```

When I use a route generator, such as `admin_project_jobs_path(@project)`, the correct route is generated; that is: `/admin/projects/awesome_project/jobs`.

The problem is that with in the ActiveAdmin Jobs controller, the `project_id` value of "awesome_project" is does not result in the correct parent object.  If I change the route generation to `admin_project_jobs_path(@project.id)` to use the ID of the object instead of it's vanity_url, that results in a path like `/admin/projects/215/jobs`, which is correctly resolved.  However ActiveAdmin generates other paths and *those* use the object, which resolve back to the vanity_url, so I can't side step this problem forever.

I've read through the code to see where the path is generated, but it seems the real solution should be in the Project or the Job ActiveAdmin object.  I've tried putting custom `find_resource` blocks into both, but haven't found something that does what is should.

Has anyone worked with such a scenario, or understands more about how the ActiveAdmin resources are resolved?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do
  belongs_to :project, :finder => :find_by_title! # or what can find your model
end
```

For more details see https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#belongs-to

Comment: Thank you, Timo, this is was very helpful. I also had to remove the custom 'find_resource' and 'def index' I had made while trying other paths as well as update all the path helpers to make index and show pages render correctly.